# Filling up a TCHAR array via for loop

Tags: c++, tchar

I am trying to loop through a TCHAR array and for each loop iteration, convert the iteration number to a string and save it into the array.

The code below is what I have:

```
#undef  UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#undef  _UNICODE
#define _UNICODE

#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>

LRESULT CALLBACK MyTextWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
 //do stuff...

#define LINES 56
static TCHAR *abc[LINES];

for(unsigned int l = 0; l<(LINES-1); l ++){
   std::wstring s = std::to_wstring(l);
   abc[l]=TEXT(s.c_str());
}
```

But it gives the following error in CodeBlocks:

error: 'Ls' was not declared in this scope

I have tried reading about TCHAR and the TEXT macro. According to here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-text the TEXT macro expects a pointer to the string which is why I tried using .c_str()

Comment: 1. You can't write a loop outside of a function; 2. That Microsoft page seems to have no relation to reality.

Comment: actually the loop is inside the WindowProc - I just amended my code to show this.

Answer (score 1):

The `TEXT` (or `_T`) macro is used for character strings (`"string"`), not variables.  It will place a leading `L` before the argument if compiling with `UNICODE` (or is it `_UNICODE`?  I never remember), so a string will become `L"string"`.

The `wstring` class will return a `wchar_t *` pointer, which you can assign to your `TCHAR *` value.  However, your `wstring` object is a local, and is destroyed at the end of the loop iteration.  You'll need to either dynamically allocate space for the `TCHAR *` values, or allocate an array of `wstring` objects to hold the constructed strings that will stick around until your done using `abc`.